# splash (landing) page for rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, splash-screen

I am creating a splash page for a rails app which contains an email field for the user to fill up and get notified when the site is completely launched.

What is the best way to go with?

Should I create a new application just for landing page **OR** should I use the same app with some variable set like ":splash => true" which would give access only to the splash page

Which would also help in deployment...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Add a splash page
2. Add a `before_action` that does a temp redirect to the splash page for all actions to your application controller.
3. when the site is launched disable that `before_action`.

Comment: Hi @glebm, Kindly provide code examples to help new beginners have a good understand of how your suggestion can be practically applied,
> #HappyCoding